# How can I preserve punctuation characters when using iconv?

Tags: iconv

The characters `«`, `»`, `‘`, `’` and several others disappear because I specify `//TRANSLIT` when converting to UTF-8 from Latin-1/CP1251:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1//TRANSLIT < in.sql | iconv -f cp1251//TRANSLIT -t utf-8 > out.sql
```

The `‘` gets converted to a `'` since it isn't in Latin1. Is there a way to keep the characters somehow intact?

So far I've been manually keeping track and replacing them with `CONSTANTSLIKETHIS` mapped to letters, and I do manual vim replacements after the conversion process is done.